# pgadmin4 connection timeout expired

Tags: database, postgresql, connection, pgadmin-4, dbeaver

Describe the bug

Hello, adding new server causes message: Unable to connect to server: connection timeout expired
Firewall is off. Password is correct

To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Go to pgAdmin -> Add new Server -> fill in the form like on the screenshots attached
Press Save
Expected behavior

Expected - server creation without any issues

Error message

Unable to connect to server: connection timeout expired

I met timeout as well, and i install it again and again, it's still timeout..

Error message

connection timeout expired